# JQuery UI autocomplete multiple words and matches with a remote datasource

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've found a number of examples that show how to highlight multiple matches e.g. if i type in "art design", I would want it to highlight it as "**art** and **design** degree"

The following example (albeit with a static array) is what I'm after:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q4jy9/1/

However, I don't know how to get this working for a remote php datasource.
Below is the current code I'm using.  Each keypress sends the term to my php and that selects matches from the database.

Is there a way I can either change the script below to allow highlighting of multiple words/matches, or change the script in the above link to work with an external datasource?

```
var termTemplate = "<span class='ui-autocomplete-term'>%s</span>";
$("#f input").autocomplete({
   source: "livesearch.php",
   open: function(e, ui) {
      var origKeyword = $("#f input").val();
      var acData = $(this).data('autocomplete');
      acData.menu.element.find('a').each(function() {
         var me = $(this);
         var regex = new RegExp(acData.term, "gi");
         me.html(me.text().replace(regex, function(matched) {
            return termTemplate.replace('%s', matched);
         }));
      });

   },
   select: function(event, ui) {
      var keyword = $("#f input").val();
      $("#f input").val('');
      window.location.href = 'MYURLHERE?VARIABLE=' + ui.item.value;
      return false;
   },
   focus: function(event, ui) {
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Maybe the code from here: http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of tborychowski, I think we have a working solution :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style type='text/css'>
   .srchHilite {background-color: yellow;}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

var termTemplate = "<span class='ui-autocomplete-term'>%s</span>";
$("#tags").autocomplete({
 source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("livesearch.php", request, function(data, status, xhr ) {

            var newmatchArry = new Array();
            var matchArry   = data.slice ();
            var srchTerms   = $.trim (request.term).split (/\s+/);

                //--- For each search term, remove non-matches.
                $.each (srchTerms, function (J, term) {
                    var regX    = new RegExp (term.value, "i");
                    matchArry   = $.map (matchArry, function (item) {
                        return regX.test (item)  ?  item  : null;
                    } );
                } );

            response(matchArry);

        });
    },

  open:   function (event, ui) {
                /*--- This function provides no hooks to the results list, so we have to trust the
                    selector, for now.
                */
                var resultsList = $("ul.ui-autocomplete > li.ui-menu-item > a");
                var srchTerm    = $.trim ( $("#tags").val () ).split (/\s+/).join ('|');

                //--- Loop through the results list and highlight the terms.
                resultsList.each ( function () {
                    var jThis   = $(this);
                    var regX    = new RegExp ('(' + srchTerm + ')', "ig");
                    var oldTxt  = jThis.text ();

                    jThis.html (oldTxt.replace (regX, '<span class="srchHilite">$1</span>') );
                } );
            }
} );

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="tags">

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (matching function is copy&pasted from your jsfiddle):

```
$("#f input").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("livesearch.php", request, function(data, status, xhr ) {

            var matchArry   = availableTags.slice ();
            var srchTerms   = $.trim (requestObj.term).split (/\s+/);

            $.each (srchTerms, function (J, term) {
                var regX  = new RegExp (term, "i");
                matchArry = $.map (matchArry, function (item) {
                    return regX.test (item)  ?  item  : null;
                });
            });

            response(matchArray);
        });
    },

    ...

});
```

This is based on jquery UI sample: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The snag here is that it's expecting an array with all the words to search through var i.e. availableTags.  We dont have the full list of words yet as this comes from the php, based on what has been typed in the input.

Comment: Hi tborychowski.  I made a couple of small alterations to your code and get it working.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Some bounty heading your way :)